# Label code chunks in regular Rstudio .r script

Tags: r, rstudio

An `.rmd` document in Rstudio is easy to navigate to the various code chunks using the little drop down in the bottom left corner of the script window.

In a regular `.r` file, functions are listed with a helpful 'f' icon and the function name and commented chunks are also listed with a helpful '#' icon, but with (untitled) next to them.

What do I need to include in my comment so the "(untitled)" will be replaced with a label?

example:

```
#----------------------------------------------------
# FirstLabel - This is the first chunk of code I want to navigate to.
#----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to create named sections - chunks.

Comment: And now I know to search for named sections instead of chunks. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `####` at the end of every comment you want to list

```
# FirstLabel - This is the first chunk of code I want to navigate to. ####
```

The nice thing about this is that you can hide everything between these comments using the drop down arrow on the left of the comment

Answer (score 2):

`####` still works, but now you can also add `----` at the end or click on `Code>Insert Section...`

```
# new section ----
```

The keyboard shortcut on windows is `CTRL+SHIFT+R` and on Mac: `CMD+SHIFT+R`

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a workaround, by using package [ARTofR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTofR/index.html) or [bannerCommenter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bannerCommenter/index.html)

For example:

```r
 ARTofR::xxx_title2('FirstLabel')
```

You will get

```r
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##                                 FirstLabel                               ----
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are other styles in this package